# How to sort a directory listing on TortoiseHG status when using Windows Explorer

Tags: tortoisesvn, tortoisehg

I've switched from subversion to mercurial and from TortoiseSVN to TortoiseHG.  I'd like to be able to sort directory listings in Windows Explorer by status (to identify uncommitted or not yet added files), but it appears that TortoiseHG doesn't have columns in Windows Explorer the way TortoiseSVN did: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-wcstatus.html#id656187.  Have I missed something or is this feature lacking in TortoiseHG's integration with Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the TortoiseHG mailing list:

Our shell extension doesn't provide any new columns.  I don't imagine
it would be difficult to add, but there hasn't been much interest.

So, it seems the capability does not exist at this time.